# How to use "strftime" in SQLite (for Android app)

Tags: android, date, sqlite, strftime

I've got a database with two table each of the tables has a column with the date.
I use strftime to get the rows of a whole month or a whole year. These are the methods in the DatabaseHelper class:

```
public Cursor GetListOfYears() {

        return myDb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y',date) AS _id 
                                  FROM table_week ORDER BY date", null);    
    }


public Cursor GetListOfMonths() {

        return myDb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%m',date) AS _id,   
                             strftime('%Y',date) AS year 
                             FROM table_week ORDER BY date", null);
    }
```

the thing is that the years method is working properly but the months one, looks to work fine for a while but when I save a new row to the table (table_week in this case) with the date from previous months or even previous years, it does weird things. I'll explain myself:

imagine there are 3 rows with dates from may, and 3 with dates from june... until there everything is working fine... now I save a new row with date in april, or february or december from last year... 1. it could work just fine 2. it could show the month in the list but when clicked can't access the rest of the information (not likely it happened a couple of times) 3. shows the correct month but the year is 0 and 4. shows wrong month but the year  is correct (this usually happens when saving a date from 2011, shows 2011 but the month is always january...)

I can't figure this out, but I'm sure that the month is the problem because the list of years works fine... any help will be appreciated, thank you very much in advance